# ZeroMQ and Majordomo protocol

Tags: design-patterns, scala, azure, akka, service-bus

I am learning ZeroMQ and came across the Majordomo Protocol. I am wondering if I'm understanding this correctly, is the use case the same as.. for example.. the Microsoft Azure AppFabric service? Would I use Majordomo if I wanted to create an AppFabric-like servie bus? Or would I do Pub/Sub+Request/Reply?

If you are not familiar, azure service bus is a way to connect applications to services (or applications to applications, etc)  -- at least for the purposes of this discussion:

[image: Azure AppFabric Service Bus]

Does it seem like this is a Majordomo protocol use case, or am I looking at a different pattern here (the bottom "direct-connection" line notwithstanding). How would eventing work (a worker initiated message)?

--

(EDIT) Thanks Adam. Distilling the question down to its essence, if I were to implement the Azure AppFabric messaging protocol with ZeroMQ, would I be using the Majordomo protocol, or would another pattern be more appropriate?

Also as reference, link to ZMQ Majordomo: http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:7

Comment: You have multiple questions that you are asking. Please try to narrow the scope to a single question (e.g., What are the differences between the Majordomo protocol and Azure's messaging protocol?)

Comment: I clarified. Hope it is satisfactory